# Send ECS Container Logs to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-fargate, aws-ecr

We've a PHP application that is pushed to ECR Fargate and we've configured an ECS task definition for it, and it works fine as a container in ECS.

I've configured aws-logs for the application and it sends the app logs normally to cloudwatch, but I'm wondering how to send the logs in a file inside the container in

> "/var/www/html/app/var/dev.log"

to the same log group that I configured when created the task definition.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer on the following link:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/send-ecs-container-logs-to-cloudwatch-logs-for-centralized-monitoring/

Just needed to install both syslog and awslogs on the php image, then use supervisord to start them with the container along with our php app. From Task definition side, create a volume and a mount point.